How to get the refreshed token in a Linnworks embed app?
I've created a private embedded app within Linnworks that displays orders in a spreadsheet format. The app is built with Vue.js and uses Axios to pull the data from Linnwork's APIs. Everything is working as it should be here, except that I'm only returning 100 orders at a time to keep things quick.
I've added a "load more orders" button which appends an additional 100 orders to the end of the sheet, but after a period of inactivity, this causes a "401 unauthorised error" because the token has expired.
Because it's an embedded app, Linnworks store the token within the src of the iframe when the app is initialised, so when it has expired, it doesn't get physically refreshed by the system.
<iframe src="https://example.com/sheet.html?token=9b11e8ff-4791-aca5-b58d-f6da84e996a6"></iframe>
Is there a way of getting the refreshed token without reloading the entire app?
I've created a private embedded app within Linnworks Amazon and eBay Integration that displays orders in a spreadsheet format. The app is built with Vue.js and uses axios to pull the data from Linnworks APIs. Everything is working as it should be here, except that I'm only returning 100 orders at a time to keep things quick.
